# Vertical dropdown submenu does not align horizontally

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I've been copying and pasting my dropdown menus for years but not fully understanding the function behind them. I decided to start my own from scratch with a minimum of code. The basics are there, but I can't figure out how to align the dropdown horizontally. I've looked at dozens of examples posted here, but I'm missing something.

Currently:

[image]

Desire:

[image]

Sample:

```css
* { font-family: verdana; 
box-sizing: border-box; /* use instead of padding-left: 0 ?? */}
li { list-style: none; padding: 4px 0;  border: 1px solid green; }
a { text-decoration: none; }
ul li a { color: blue; }
ul li ul li a { color: red; }
ul li a:hover { opacity: 0.3; }

/*--------------
 Salient code
----------------*/

ul li {
  float: left; /* horizontal */
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  /* left: auto; */
  display: block
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none; /* left: -999em; */
  top: 28px;
  padding-left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Top One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Three</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Middle One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Middle Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Middle Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul` gets a default `padding-left` applied via the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: You shouldn't move things off screen by 999em as it means that the browsers has to create a 999em box (which can reduce your render times) - try using display none instead.  Also instead of using `top: 28px` it would probably be better to use 100% as then if any browser doesn't render that li as 28px, it will still be placed below the li

Comment: I also noted that normally I have a reset file that contains `box-sizing: border-box;` which negates the need for `padding-left: 0`

Comment: Addressing Pete's comment about using `display:none`— great idea, but it's difficult, if not impossible, to build in transitions for that spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set padding-left to zero on your UL. Marked up code below.

```css
* {
  font-family: verdana;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: blue;
}

ul li ul li a {
  color: red;
}

ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}


/*--------------
 Salient code
----------------*/

ul li {
  float: left;
  /* horizontal */
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
  top: 28px;
  /* Just set padding-left to zero here */
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Top One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Top Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Top Three</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Middle One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Middle Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Middle Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```